# Applying Styles With Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I am trying to create a custom control called `PieceImage` that contains one of several predefined `Canvas` elements. I have defined these Canvases in a `ResourceDictionary` called PieceImageDictionary.xaml. I have set up some dependency properties in `PieceImage`, `Color1` and `Color2`, that I'd like to bind to the `Fill` and `Stroke` of the paths in the Canvases. I have a pretty good understanding of custom controls and simple databinding but styles are a little confusing to me.

So basically I have a `ResourceDictionary` with Canvases that I am treating as images and I want be able to have multiple `PieceImage` `Control` instances that can each choose one of these images independently (not a global style) and I want to be able to set the colors using a `DependencyProperty` on the `PieceImage` Controls.

I have tried wrapping my Canvases in `ControlTemplates` but for whatever reason "`Canvas`" is not a valid `TargetType`.

I got it to apply this template if I set the `TargetType` to "`Control`" however when I tried adding `TemplateBinding` to the `Paths`, the Property I wanted to set `(Color1)` couldn't be found. I kind of understand this because the `Color1` property is in my `PieceImage` control, so `TemplateBinding` to a `Control` or even a `Canvas` won't work.

I then tried `RelativeBinding` with an `AncestorType` of "`PieceImage`" but this doesn't work either. No error, just a blank `Canvas`. I've tried calling `UpdateLayout()` and `InvalidateVisual()` on the `Canvas` just in case but no change.

I tried using a `XamlReader` and Writer to create these canvases instead of using templates, which initially worked when I statically defined the colors but when I tried to add the `RelativeBinding` I got a Xaml Parse Error saying it couldnt create the type from the string "`local:PieceImage`"

I tried adding a binding in the code but also got a blank `Canvas`. I will admit I don't know much about coding bindings, this was my implementation:

```cs
var binding = new Binding(Color1Property.Name);
binding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.TemplatedParent);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(path, Path.FillProperty, binding);
```

Here is my base code, I've cleaned out all the failed attempts for clarity because it would otherwise be a mess.

PieceImage.cs

```cs
public class PieceImage : Control
{
    private Canvas _canvas;
    static PieceImage()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(PieceImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(PieceImage)));
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Color1Property = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Color1), typeof(Brush), typeof(PieceImage), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.BlanchedAlmond));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Color2Property = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Color2), typeof(Brush), typeof(PieceImage), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.DarkGray));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PieceTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(PieceType), typeof(Enums.PieceType), typeof(PieceImage), new PropertyMetadata(Enums.PieceType.Pawn));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SwapColorsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SwapColors), typeof(bool), typeof(PieceImage), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public Brush Color1
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(Color1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Color1Property, value); }
    }
    public Brush Color2
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(Color2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Color2Property, value); }
    }
    public Enums.PieceType PieceType
    {
        get { return (Enums.PieceType)GetValue(PieceTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PieceTypeProperty, value); }
    }
    public bool SwapColors
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(SwapColorsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SwapColorsProperty, value); }
    }
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _canvas = Template.FindName("PART_Canvas", this) as Canvas;
        //Here is where most of my logic would go when I was loading xaml or coding bindings
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml (partial)

```xaml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wagner.Chess.UI.Controls">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="\pieceimagedictionary.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PieceImage}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:PieceImage">
                    <Canvas x:Name="PART_Canvas"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

PieceImageDictionary.xaml

```xaml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wagner.Chess.UI.Controls">
    <Canvas Height="64" Width="64"  x:Key="BishopImage">
        <Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PieceImage,AncestorLevel=2,Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Color1}"
              Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PieceImage,AncestorLevel=2,Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Color2}"
              StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeMiterLimit="1" StrokeLineJoin="Round">
                <Path.Data>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M 9,36 C 12.39,35.03 19.11,36.43 22.5,34 C 25.89,36.43 32.61,35.03 36,36 C 36,36 37.65,36.54 39,38
                                      C 38.32,38.97 37.35,38.99 36,38.5 C 32.61,37.53 25.89,38.96 22.5,37.5 C 19.11,38.96 12.39,37.53 9,38.5 C 7.65,38.99
                                      6.68,38.97 6,38 C 7.35,36.54 9,36 9,36 z"/>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M 15,32 C 17.5,34.5 27.5,34.5 30,32 C 30.5,30.5 30,30 30,30 C 30,27.5 27.5,26 27.5,26 C 33,24.5 33.5,14.5
                                      22.5,10.5 C 11.5,14.5 12,24.5 17.5,26 C 17.5,26 15,27.5 15,30 C 15,30 14.5,30.5 15,32 z"/>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M 25 8 A 2.5 2.5 0 1 1  20,8 A 2.5 2.5 0 1 1  25 8 z"/>
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        <Path Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PieceImage,AncestorLevel=2,Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Color2}"
               StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeMiterLimit="1" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Miter">
                <Path.Data>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M 17.5,26 L 27.5,26 M 15,30 L 30,30 M 22.5,15.5 L 22.5,20.5 M 20,18 L 25,18" />
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.42222222222" ScaleY="1.42222222222"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        </Canvas>
    <Canvas Height="64" Width="64" x:Key="KnightImage">
        <Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PieceImage,AncestorLevel=2,Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Color1}"
              Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PieceImage,AncestorLevel=2,Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Color2}"
              StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeMiterLimit="1"  StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round">
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M 22,10 C 32.5,11 38.5,18 38,39 L 15,39 C 15,30 25,32.5 23,18"/>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M 24,18 C 24.38,20.91 18.45,25.37 16,27 C 13,29 13.18,31.34 11,31 C 9.958,30.06 12.41,27.96 11,28 C 10,28 11.19,29.23 10,
                                  30 C 9,30 5.997,31 6,26 C 6,24 12,14 12,14 C 12,14 13.89,12.1 14,10.5 C 13.27,9.506 13.5,8.5 13.5,7.5 C 14.5,6.5 16.5,10 16.5,10 L 
                                  18.5,10 C 18.5,10 19.28,8.008 21,7 C 22,7 22,10 22,10"/>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PieceImage,AncestorLevel=2,Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Color2}"
              Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PieceImage,AncestorLevel=2,Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Color2}"
              StrokeThickness="0.5" StrokeMiterLimit="1" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round">
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M 9.5 25.5 A 0.5 0.5 0 1 1 8.5,25.5 A 0.5 0.5 0 1 1 9.5 25.5 z"/>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M 15 15.5 A 0.5 1.5 0 1 1  14,15.5 A 0.5 1.5 0 1 1  15 15.5 z">
                        <PathGeometry.Transform>
                            <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.866,0.5,-0.5,0.866,9.693,-5.173"/>
                        </PathGeometry.Transform>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.42222222222" ScaleY="1.42222222222"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I was hoping someone could provide some tips or point me in the right direction because MSDocs have guides for `StyleSelectors` and `DataTemplateSelectors` both of which are more for data item styling rather than setting another variable control using a style.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you want to show a piece `Canvas` based on the `PieceType` in a your `PieceImage` control. Then, you do not have to nest a `Canvas` inside another `Canvas`. You can replace the `Canvas` in your `PieceImage` template with a `ContentPresenter` (`PART_ContentPresenter`).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PieceImage}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:PieceImage">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentPresenter"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

In your `PieceImage` control, you can then search for the corresponding `PieceType` resource (`Canvas`) using the [`FindResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource?view=net-5.0) method and assign it to the `ContentPresenter`. Here I assume that we can map the `PieceType` using the pattern `<Enum Constant Name>Image`. If it is more complex, you could use a dictionary or a custom converter.

```
public class PieceImage : Control
{
   private ContentPresenter _contentPresenter;

   // ...your constructor, dependency property definitions, etc..

   public override void OnApplyTemplate()
   {
      base.OnApplyTemplate();

      _contentPresenter = Template.FindName("PART_ContentPresenter", this) as ContentPresenter;

      if (_contentPresenter != null)
         _contentPresenter.Content = FindPieceImage();
   }

   private Canvas FindPieceImage()
   {
      var pieceTypeName = PieceType.ToString();
      var pieceTypeCanvasKey = $"{pieceTypeName}Image";
      return FindResource(pieceTypeCanvasKey) as Canvas;
   }
}
```

Since the original `Canvas` in the control template is gone, remove **all** the `AncestorLevel=2` attributes in your piece images, otherwise the binding source will not be found. Furthermore, add  [`x:Shared="False"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xshared-attribute) to your `Canvas`es. This is important, because your piece images are now potentially used multiple times (I guess your are building a chess board), but without setting `x:Shared` to `false` the **same instances** will be reused.

> When set to `false`, modifies WPF resource-retrieval behavior so that requests for the attributed resource create a new instance for each request instead of sharing the same instance for all requests.

This is problematic, because each control can only have a single parent element. This means that when you would assign the same `Canvas` instance multiple times, only the last element will get it as child. You can imagine a chess board where only the last assinged pieces are shown and the rest of the board is empty. Here is an excerpt of the modifications to your code.

```
<Canvas Height="64" Width="64"  x:Key="BishopImage"  x:Shared="False">
    <Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PieceImage,Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Color1}"
          Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PieceImage,Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Color2}"
          StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeMiterLimit="1" StrokeLineJoin="Round">
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M 9,36 C 12.39,35.03 19.11,36.43 22.5,34 C 25.89,36.43 32.61,35.03 36,36 C 36,36 37.65,36.54 39,38
                                  C 38.32,38.97 37.35,38.99 36,38.5 C 32.61,37.53 25.89,38.96 22.5,37.5 C 19.11,38.96 12.39,37.53 9,38.5 C 7.65,38.99
                                  6.68,38.97 6,38 C 7.35,36.54 9,36 9,36 z"/>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M 15,32 C 17.5,34.5 27.5,34.5 30,32 C 30.5,30.5 30,30 30,30 C 30,27.5 27.5,26 27.5,26 C 33,24.5 33.5,14.5
                                  22.5,10.5 C 11.5,14.5 12,24.5 17.5,26 C 17.5,26 15,27.5 15,30 C 15,30 14.5,30.5 15,32 z"/>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M 25 8 A 2.5 2.5 0 1 1  20,8 A 2.5 2.5 0 1 1  25 8 z"/>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <!-- ...other markup code. -->
```

The bindings will work now and resolve to `PieceImage` without any additional code or markup.

Comment: Thanks! This works well. The only minor issue with this was x:Shared only working if I take the Canvases out of PieceImageDictionary.xaml and put them directly in App.xaml but that's not a huge problem. I also didn't know the AncestorLevel was causing problems, I had assumed that it was a max limit to ascend before giving up. I appreciate it!

Comment: @MichaelWagner Contrarily, the `AncestorLevel` lets you _skip_ matching elements. Say you have  multiple `PieceImage` controls in your visual tree, then an `AncestorLevel` of `2` would _skip_ the nearest `PieceImage` and bind to the next one found. If no matching element is found, the search will continue automatically to the "max limit", which is the root of the visual tree, regardless of the `AncestorLevel`.